# Android show dialog causes illegal state exception if activity recreated

Tags: java, android, dialog, illegalstateexception, fragmenttransaction

There are three activities: `Login`, `Main` and `Profile`

Obviously from `Login` you can go to `Main`. There is a `Button` that calls `AppCompatDialogFragment` in `Main`.

```
    BalanceCalculationDialog dialog = BalanceCalculationDialog.newInstance(model);
    dialog.setListener(this);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```

1. If I user enters `Main` for the first time dialog shows.
2. If user goes to `Profile` and then backs dialog shows.
3. If user goes out from `Main` (`finish()` with `Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flags) and tries to see `dialog` he sees  an error.

   ```
       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after 
        onSaveInstanceState....CheckStateLoss()...
   ```

As far as I know it caused because "Transaction cannot be commited after `onSaveInstanceState()`".

I tried to override this method leaving empty body, not calling `super` and didn't work.

Then I found another way to solve problem, which worked:

```
@Override
public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
    try {
       FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, tag);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("ILLEGAL", "Exception", e);
    }
 }
```

Nevertheless I don't understand why it works this way -> Number of catching `IllegalStateException` equals the number of recreating `Main`. For example I log out 20 times - then I will have 20 catching of mentioned exception. So I don't find this solution as the right one.

In addition, I have other activities that can call another dialogs. These activities also can be finished with `finish()` and when user opens one of them again he doesn't have the issue.

I would be very glad to have proper explanation of such behaviour and right way of solving it. Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

Reason of this issue was usage of `RxJava` `EventBus`. When I switched to `Otto Eventbus` problem disappeared. `RxJava` allows you to send and get messages without `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` that can cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: When you show the dialog when you leave 'Main' are you showing it in onFinish? in which case you can't do that which is what the error says, because the activity is being closed so the dialog has no context. Not sure how you've set it up but you could show the error on the Login page.

Comment: @RobVoisey Dialog is shown only on button click in `Main`

Answer (score 4):

The exception was thrown because you attempted to commit a `FragmentTransaction` after the activity’s state had been saved, resulting in a phenomenon known as `Activity` state loss. Before we get into the details of what this actually means, however, let’s first take a look at what happens under-the-hood when `onSaveInstanceState()` is called. Android applications have very little control over their destiny within the Android runtime environment. The Android system has the power to terminate processes at any time to free up memory, and background activities may be killed with little to no warning as a result. To ensure that this sometimes erratic behavior remains hidden from the user, the framework gives each `Activity` a chance to save its state by calling its `onSaveInstanceState()` method before making the Activity vulnerable to destruction. When the saved state is later restored, the user will be given the perception that they are seamlessly switching between foreground and background activities, regardless of whether or not the Activity had been killed by the system.

When the framework calls `onSaveInstanceState()`, it passes the method a `Bundle` object for the `Activity` to use to save its state, and the `Activity` records in it the state of its dialogs, fragments, and views. When the method returns, the system parcels the `Bundle` object across a Binder interface to the System Server process, where it is safely stored away. When the system later decides to recreate the `Activity`, it sends this same `Bundle` object back to the application, for it to use to restore the Activity’s old state.

So why then is the exception thrown? Well, the problem stems from the fact that these `Bundle` objects represent a snapshot of an `Activity` at the moment `onSaveInstanceState()` was called, and nothing more. That means when you call `FragmentTransaction#commit()` after `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, the transaction won’t be remembered because it was never recorded as part of the Activity’s state in the first place. From the user’s point of view, the transaction will appear to be lost, resulting in accidental UI state loss. In order to protect the user experience, Android avoids state loss at all costs, and simply throws an `IllegalStateException` whenever it occurs.

**Solution** for this exception is

- Be careful when committing transactions inside `Activity` lifecycle methods. A large majority of applications will only ever commit transactions the very first time `onCreate()` is called and/or in response to user input, and will never face any problems as a result. However, as your transactions begin to venture out into the other `Activity` lifecycle methods, such as `onActivityResult()`, `onStart()`, and `onResume()`, things can get a little tricky. For example, you should not commit transactions inside the `FragmentActivity#onResume()` method, as there are some cases in which the method can be called before the activity’s state has been restored (see the documentation for more information). If your application requires committing a transaction in an `Activity` lifecycle method other than `onCreate()`, do it in either `FragmentActivity#onResumeFragments()` or `Activity#onPostResume()`. These two methods are guaranteed to be called after the Activity has been restored to its original state, and therefore avoid the possibility of state loss all together. (As an example of how this can be done, check out my answer to this StackOverflow question for some ideas on how to commit FragmentTransactions in response to calls made to the `Activity#onActivityResult()` method).
- Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods. This includes commonly used methods such as `AsyncTask#onPostExecute()` and `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks#onLoadFinished()`. The problem with performing transactions in these methods is that they have no knowledge of the current state of the `Activity` lifecycle when they are called. For example, consider the following sequence of events:
  An activity executes an `AsyncTask`.

  1. The user presses the “Home” key, causing the activity’s
     `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onStop()` methods to be called.
  2. The AsyncTask completes and `onPostExecute()` is called, unaware that the
  3. Activity has since been stopped. A FragmentTransaction is committed
     inside the `onPostExecute()` method, causing an exception to be thrown.
     In general, the best way to avoid the exception in these cases is to
     simply avoid committing transactions in asynchronous callback methods
     all together.
- Use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` only as a last resort. The only difference between calling `commit()` and `commitAllowingStateLoss()` is that the latter will not throw an exception if state loss occurs. Usually you don’t want to use this method because it implies that there is a possibility that state loss could happen. The better solution, of course, is to write your application so that `commit()` is guaranteed to be called before the activity’s state has been saved, as this will result in a better user experience. Unless the possibility of state loss can’t be avoided, `commitAllowingStateLoss()` should not be used.

But I have to agree that this is an Android framework design defect. Google devs try to fix it over many version. But seems like there is no good approach to work-around this. Just understand the life cycle and remember to check the state of activity carefully before committing transaction

Comment: I have already read these info copied from the article. Unfortunately it doesn't help neither to understand my issue when some activity can create dialog being recreated and other don't, nor to find right solution. My dialog can be called only after `onResume`, there are no asynch calls and even `commitAllowingStateLoss()` doesn't work perfectly. Sorry, you didn't tell me anything new :(

Comment: exactly, it makes no sense. I have a dialog I call on `onClick` and yet I still get this exception.